# limits, boundary, closure, and exterior points of $ I_n =\left [ \frac{1}{2n+1}, \frac{1}{2n} \right]$ and $S= \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n$

Tags: real-analysis

> Quoting an example:
>
> for $$ n \geq 1$$
>
> $$ I_n = \left[ \frac{1}{2n+1}, \frac{1}{2n} \right]$$ and $$ S= \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n$$
>
> (a) The set of limit points of $S$ is $S \cup \{0\}$
>
> (b) The set of boundary points $$\partial S = \left\{ x | x=0 \text{ or }x =\frac{1}{n} (n \geq 2) \right\} $$
>
> (c) the closure  $$\bar S = S \cup \{0\}$$
>
> (d) the exterior of S $$ (- \infty,0) \cup \left[ \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2n+2}, \frac{1}{2n+1}\right)\right] \cup \left( \frac{1}{2}, \infty \right)$$

Regarding (a) I understood that $x_0$ is a limit point of S if every *deleted neighborhood* of $x_0$ contains a point of $S$,

$0$ is a limit because $((0-1,0+1) \setminus \{0\} ) \cap S = $ contain the elements of S?

S is a limit because $((S-1,S+1) \setminus S ) \cap S = ???$

Is this reasoning correct?

Regarding the rest, the book does not elaborate, trying to find some youtube videos unsuccessfully. I have difficulty to determine the possible reasoning behind the solutions.

Any input is much appreciated

Regarding

Comment: Given a metric space $X$ with metric $d(y, z)$, and a set $S \subset X$, a point $x$ of $X$ is by definition a limit point for $S$ if, $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists s \in S: d(x - s) < \epsilon$. For real numbers, the metric is of course absolute value: $d(y, z) = |y - z|$. So in your case, if we fix $\epsilon > 0$ then since $|\frac{1}{2n + 1} - 0| < \epsilon$ for $n$ large enough, and $\frac{1}{2n+1} \in S$, we know that $0$ is a limit point of $S$.

Comment: Also, in case you don't know what a "metric space" is, just read the definition I gave as "if $S \subset \mathbb{R}$, then a limit point $x$ of $S$ is one for which $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists s \in S: |x - s| < \epsilon$".